# How to package a closed-source AAR library with stub java files

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aar

I'm using Android Studio 2.3 to create a hardware interface library that we can distribute to partners. I would like the inner workings of the library to be closed-source, but provide documented 'stub' classes and methods that can be viewed in Android Studio.

I tried compiling my library and importing the AAR to another project, and Android Studio lets me use the classes correctly, but it doesn't show any java files or documentation in the new project.

Is there a standard practice for how to achieve this? I'm just moving into Android development from C, so I'm used to being able to provide header files with my libraries. It seems like there should be a way to achieve something similar without too much hacking.

Comment: "Is there a standard practice for how to achieve this?" -- you can't, at least for how I would define the term "stub".

Comment: Is there any way to achieve my larger goal of just having the IDE be able to provide the classes, methods, and their Javadoc headers when you import the library?

Comment: JavaDocs are not distributed in the AAR. If you are publishing your AAR in an artifact repository, you can distribute the JavaDocs alongside the AAR, and with the proper metadata (e.g., POM file for a Maven-style repo), developers can get the docs.